# Pytest tries to collect wrong classes

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a Python module:

```
.
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── suite.py
├── docs
├── pyproject.toml
├── pytest.ini
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_config.py
│   ├── test_description.py
│   ├── test_id.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── test_schema.py
└── tox.ini
```

When I run `pytest` with  this `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-modules
testpaths = tests
python_files = test_*.py
python_classes = Test*
```

Pytest tries to collect tests inside the `module`. I have a `TestSuite` in my module, and I get this error:

```
PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestSuite' 
because it has a __init__ constructor
```

Of course, this is not a test. How to prevent pytest to prevent from false positive?

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set the magic `__test__` attribute to `False` on all classes that `pytest` should skip for any reason, including the ones that clash with the naming rules from [`python_classes`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#confval-python_classes). Example: create a `conftest.py` in your project's root directory with the contents

```
from module.suite import TestSuite

TestSuite.__test__ = False
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell pytest in its own config file rather than modifying the classes?

Comment: @nowox no. Once you have imported `TestSuite` somewhere in a test module, it is a valid object to be collected. You can refactor the test code and keep `TestSuite` imports in some `utils` module so `TestSuite` is not leaked into test modules, but IMO it's easier just to set the `__test__` attribute on affected classes.

Comment: @nowox although you could use an alias for the name in test modules, so e.g. using `from module.suite import TestSuite as Alias` should get rid of the warning as well. But again, it might be a hassle to do the renaming just to get rid of the warning; might be even easier to just ignore the warning via [`filterwarnings`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#confval-filterwarnings) if you don't want to change the code at all.